# The page you requested was not found

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

### 404 Page Not Found

I am visiting my page by this link: www.mypage.com/job

I had developed a website in Codeigniter. All is working fine on my local server when i use xampp, but the problem is when I upload it online. The error I am facing is `404 Page Not Found`. My directory structure is like this:

- `Public_html` (host main folder)
- `job` (my website folder)
- `the remaining files and folder with in my main folder job.`

### config/config.php file

- `$config['base_url'] = '';`
- $config['index_page'] = '';

### config/route.php file

- `$route['default_controller'] = '';`

### Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fill this part with true address

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

For example `"http://example.com/"`

If it dosen't work check your .htaccess file

Comment: can i type the folder name after my website name like this: www.example.com/folder

Comment: and what should i do with .htaccess file

Comment: what should I do with .htaccess file

Comment: it could be something like this :
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: any way use codeigniter forum and you will find more info

Comment: I have find this in .htaccess file.
# HTID:709469: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW
php_value display_errors 1
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:709469: